# Django Startup script for loading values into tables

Tags: django, django-models

There are 6 tables in DB out of it 3 will have same values everytime like static values  these values need to be loaded into tables when we do python manage.py runserver.
what will be the approach for this do i need to have a script for it 
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would load them into a CONTEXT_PROCESSOR so that they are available in all templates.

if you need it available as global variables, simple load them in a custom script.py file that you import into the views.py file you need it in.

edit:

you should also consider caching the results from the database and either saving in the SESSION or look into running memcached if the site could see a lot of traffic.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some tables which are having same values everytime(staic values).
You can write your own [fixture][1] which define all values we are going to store into those tables.
You can create a directory of name  `fixtures` into app folder. 
Directory example :

```
|- my_app
|    |- fixtures
|           |- static_content.json
```

static_content.json can looks like

```
[
  {
    "model": "myapp.model1",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "first_name": "test",
      "last_name": "Test_last"
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "myapp.model2",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "age": "21",
      "email": "foo@foo.com"
    }
  }
]
```

before starting server by `python manage.py runserver` we can load our fixtures into our database by using below command.

```
python manage.py loaddata <fixturename>
Ex.   python manage.py loaddata my_app/static_content.json
```

above command will work as a startup script for loading values into db tables.

Comment: wouldn't this be more for using in a test environment, where you might change the data during a test and want to be able to quickly restore the database state?

Comment: You can consider it in that way too but fixtures use more than using in a test environment, but my suggestion for fixtures was because you were looking for a startup script for loading values into db tables.

Comment: I may have read his question wrong; my approach solves the, you want to put configuration values in the database and load them on startup/needed. Yours solves the need to pre-populate the database with some values on startup. similar, but different needs really. Thanks for the insights.